# What is the translation for "over-ordering"?

Tags: tradução, palavra-para-ideia

I know that in the sentence:

> The reduction of “over-ordering” was great for our results!

"over-ordering" can be translated as "Encomenda excessiva" but what if we are talking about over-ordering food at a McDonalds?

As in I go to MacDonals and I order some food. After eating I would feel overfilled, thus I could say:

> I over-ordered

Comment: Over-ordering would be good, reduction of over-ordering,whatever that is, would reduce the results. How do you say in Portuguese. What do you mean by over-ordering? Hm?

Comment: @Lambie. When you over-order you are wasting resources, because you ordered things you don't need. Thus reducing over-ordering brings better results.

Comment: @Bruno Costa So the manager is not over-ordering food?? Less waste? OK. In your answer, you made it sound like people eating at MacDonalds are ordering too much food.

Comment: Hugo, your question should include the **meaning** of over-ordering, and of the sentence that you are trying to translate. As an example, it is not clear whether that over-ordering is by the customers or by the store manager, and those two different meanings could get translated differently.

Comment: I brought this question to [meta](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/291/a-pergunta-what-is-the-translation-for-over-ordering-nao-est%C3%A1-a-ter-feedbac)

Comment: At [EL&U](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/374493/can-say-that-i-over-ordered-food-in-a-restaurant-as-a-client) most comments affirm that no native speaker would say "over-ordered food at MacDonald's" even though they might understand it, provided the context was clear. Instead, they would say "I ordered too much food".  That's what you read in most comments and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Instead of saying that you over-ordered you say that you bought too much, example:

> Comprei comida demais no MacDonalds (I bought too much food at MacDonalds)

---

**1. Definition and usage of to order (encomendar) in portuguese**

The problem is that the word "encomenda" usually implies a lapse of time between the buy and the usage/consumption of an item. [See the definitions at priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/encomendar)

> en·co·men·dar - Conjugar verbo transitivo
>
> 1. Mandar fazer.
> 2. Encarregar de fazer ou dizer (alguma coisa).
> 3. Proceder à encomendação de.
> 4. Nomear (pároco encomendado). verbo pronominal
> 5. Entregar-se (à protecção de alguém).

In fact you may take that a step further and say that a delivery is expected, or that the person needs to pick it up.

This happens more frequently over the phone, or internet. It can also happen at the shop when the item is not available, or takes time to prepare, consider for example a pizza.

Let's consider the following examples.

> Encomendei leitão para o jantar. (I ordered piglet for dinner)
>
> Encomendei frango, mas vou buscá-lo á loja. (I ordered chicken, but I am picking it up at the shop)
>
> Quero encomendar uma pizza para o jantar. (I want to order a pizza for the dinner)

**2. An item that you are buying right now is not a "encomenda" it's a "compra"**

In the situations we purchase an item and have it handed out in that moment we would prefer the usage of compra(r).

> Eu comprei um relógio. (I bought a watch)

So over-ordering food in MacDonalds would translate as follows:

> Comprei demasiada comida no MacDonalds (I bought too much food in MacDonalds)

**3. You can use the same concept with encomenda.**

> Encomendei demasiado leitão. (I over-ordered piglet)

Notice however, that act of over-ordering happened in the past in such cenario. It couldn't really happen in the future, unless you are over-ordering on purpose.

> Vou encomendar muito leitão (I am going to over-order piglet)

**4. Over-ordering in financial context**

In a financial context, the usage of "over-ordering" could be translated as "encomenda excessiva", as noted in the title. The following sentence

> We reduced over-ordering by 30% compared to last year

Could be translated as follows

> Reduzimos as encomendas excessivas por 30%, em comparação com o ano anterior

Comment: "Encomendei leitão em excesso", "Encomendei leitão demais", "Encomendei leitão mais do que o necessário", "Encomendei leitão em demasia" (todas opções melhores do que usar demasiado, pelo menos em pt-BR)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52008/discussion-between-bruno-costa-and-lambie).

Comment: Essa pergunta em inglês não pode ter nada a ver com pedido de comida feita pelos clientes. Só pode ter a ver com os resultados comercias da empresa. Se pede comida em um restaurante mas um restaurante tem um volume de compras de alimentos. Até ficar claro isso para todos aqui, a barco vai continuar se afundando....

Answer (score 1):

***A redução de compras excessivas foi ótima para nossos resultados!***

Esse texto é sobre o gerenciamento de restaurantes:

> Os volumes de compras devem ser feitos com critério e embasados em
>   planejamento e análise de consumo médio. Compras excessivas podem causar
>   um acúmulo de materiais que estejam acima da capacidade de
>   armazenamento, o que poderia causar uma diminuição do tempo de vida útil
>   dos alimentos, podendo até ser perdidos, ***aumentando-se o custo da operação***.

https://repositorio.ufsc.br/xmlui/bitstream/handle/123456789/83249/192881.pdf?sequence=1

Comment: You did not adress the use case of the asker: what if we are talking about over-ordering food at a McDonalds

Comment: @Bruno Costa 1) Já tentei explicar que ***em inglês*** não existe "over ordering" em relação aos clientes pedindo comida em um restaurante. Pensar que sim demostra falta de conhecimentos do/em inglês. Sejamos francos, quém falaria de "encomenda excessiva" nesse contexto??? Resposta: Ninguém. 2) O único contexto que faz sentido em termos de linguagem em inglês é fazer pedidos ou encomendas em termos dos volumes de alimentos que faz um restaurante; que a gerência faz. Então, o seu "voto a menos" não tem nenhum sentido e a sua pregunta, dado a semántica errada da pregunta, também não.

Comment: Concordo com você ipsis litteris, @Lambie

Comment: @Centaurus Muito obrigada.

Comment: A malta do [english stackexchange](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/374493/can-say-that-i-over-ordered-food-in-a-restaurant-as-a-client) nao concorda com isso e o [google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+over-ordered+food%22&gws_rd=cr&ei=GCmqWMXpDqLFgAbY2rTAAw) também nao.

Comment: (Para além da validação pelos exemplos de uso, que o Bruno deu:) O conceito de *over-ordering* por parte dos clientes existe e é um problema real para restaurantes de rodízio, por exemplo, porque um cliente de um *all-you-can-eat* não pagaria os desperdícios que pusesse no prato e não comesse - porque a refeição tem o mesmo preço independentemente de quanto se coma. (Para evitar isso, alguns rodízios adicionam um pagamento extra a quem deixar desperdícios.)

Comment: @ANeves, em inglês, o cliente que pedi demais num rodizio all-you-can eat não se diria over-ordering. Você está misturando tudo com o feijão.

Comment: You're right.  At EL&U [most comments and answers](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/374493/can-say-that-i-over-ordered-food-in-a-restaurant-as-a-client)  affirm that no native speaker would say "over-ordered food at MacDonald's" even though they might understand it provided the context was clear. Instead, they would say "I ordered too much food". That's what has been posted in most comments and answers.

Comment: @Centaurus There is that. But there is also MacDonald's as a business over-ordering too many food items from suppliers. And the OP refuses to clarify. And that is the point I have been making from the beginning of all this rebolada. :)

Comment: The original question, asked on Jan 17th, was "How to say In Portuguese: The reduction of "over-ordering" was great for our results!" but the whole question was edited on Feb 21st by one of the answerers and our answers simply don't fit anymore.

Comment: @Centaurus Neither the original question nor the question in its present form reflect the two basic meanings I have pointed out. The first sentence can only be business related and the second can only be about ordering too much to eat in a restaurant. So, the editing has made no difference to this basic issue, which I am now done with (as I have explained it over and over and over). Tchau,.. :).

Answer (score -1):

**Your question is very simple**: How can we say "The reduction of over-ordering was great for our results." in Portuguese?

**The answer is also simple**: although you can say it in several different ways, **only a few are idiomatic** in pt-BR.  "To order" can be translated as "pedir", "encomendar", "comprar".  Depending on context, I can suggest the following translations:

> - "Encomendar **apenas o necessário** foi essencial para nossos resultados."
> - "Comprar **nada mais que o necessário** foi muito bom para os nossos resultados"
> - "**Não** pedir **mais que o necessário** nos trouxe excelentes resultados."
> - "Não comprar **nada além do necessário**, foi vital para nossos resultados.

Comment: Que tem a ver com a pregunta??

Comment: You did not adress the use case of the asker: `what if we are talking about over-ordering food at a McDonalds`

Comment: @Centaurus Acho que você traduziu direitinho a ideia. Claro, não existe over-ordering food at McDonalds que não tenha a ver com resultados do negócio. Resultados só pode ser a grana que se faz.

Comment: A malta do [english stackexchange](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/374493/can-say-that-i-over-ordered-food-in-a-restaurant-as-a-client) nao concorda com isso e o [google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+over-ordered+food%22&gws_rd=cr&ei=GCmqWMXpDqLFgAbY2rTAAw) também nao.

Comment: @Lambie   You're right.  At EL&U [**most comments and answers**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/374493/can-say-that-i-over-ordered-food-in-a-restaurant-as-a-client)  affirm that no native speaker would say "over-ordered food at MacDonald's" even though they might understand it provided the context was clear. Instead, they would say "I ordered too much food". That's what has been posted in most comments and answers.

Comment: Olá Centaurus. Eu não me vi na obrigacão de o a Avisar, aliás até tem vezes que edito a minha resposta e nao aviso os comentadores caso tenham apontado a falha. Esta edição foi aprovada pelo autor da pergunta. Isto quer dizer que eu não mudei o sentido à pergunta, isto também quer dizer que você não interpertou bem a pergunta.